# How to add data in array on button click?

Tags: android, arrays

```
    int size = mcq.size();


    String arr[] = null;
    int i;
    {


        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {


            if (op1.isPressed()) {
                arr[i] = tv1.getText().toString();
                // Log.e("Array",arr[i]);

            } else if (op2.isPressed()) {
                arr[i] = tv2.getText().toString();
                //Log.e("Array",arr[i]);

            } else if (op3.isPressed()) {
                arr[i] = tv3.getText().toString();
                //  Log.e("Array",arr[i]);


            } else if (op4.isPressed()) {
                arr[i] = tv4.getText().toString();
                //Log.e("Array",arr[i]);


            }
```

I am trying to store the data in an array when the button is pressed,but it always shows null.And when the for loop is over I want to display my array.

Comment: you may consider using ArrayList

Comment: the problem in ArrayList is that it adds the duplicate value@ndeokar

Comment: it has .contains() method to check for duplication

Comment: you may debug and find out why array is null after for loop

Comment: Ok,if I clicked op1,op2,op3 and op4 then it will add all the data for the same position,which I don, not want.For a position I want only one value.So can u tell me if it solves the problem I will use it @ndeokar

Comment: it won't add at same position... hows that possible to press op1...op4 at same time? list.add() adds object to the top

Answer (score 2):

here , Arrays in Java have a size so u cannot do like this. Instead of this 
use list,

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Inorder to do using String array :

```
String[] arr = new String[SIZEDEFNE HERE];
```

For ur answer :

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i;
        {
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (op1.isPressed()) {
                    arr.add(tv1.getText().toString()); 
                } else if (op2.isPressed()) {
                    arr.add(tv2.getText().toString()); 

                } else if (op3.isPressed()) {
                    arr.add(tv3.getText().toString()); 

                } else if (op4.isPressed()) {
                    arr.add(tv4.getText().toString()); 
                }
```

Retrive value using

```
String s = arr.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your string array is `null`. Declare it with the size as

`String[] arr = new String[size];`

Comment: Still getting null

Comment: You may have not initialized your `TextView`'s (tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4) properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Array List`. use the following code in your main java

```
final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId)
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        list.add(editText.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplication in arraylist .You can use arraylist for faster then String array

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Krishna");
    list.add("Krishna");
    list.add("Kishan");
    list.add("Krishn");
    list.add("Aryan");
    list.add("Harm");

System.out.println("List"+list);
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
hs.addAll(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(hs);
```